# Dashed curve in simple R plot. Lty=2 does not seem to be working

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am having trouble with getting a simple plot to return a dotted line (lty=2). This is a very elementary problem, but I can't seem to find the solution. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this. My code is below:

```
par(family="serif", yaxs="i", xaxs="i")

#Empty plot with axes labeled 
plot(dataset1[,6]~dataset2[,5], ann=FALSE, cex.axis=1.5, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", lty=1, type="n")
title(xlab="X axis title (%)", ylab="Y axis title", cex.lab=1.5)
axis(side=1, at=c(0,10,20, 30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), cex.axis=1.5)


#Add curves
lines(dataset1[,6]~dataset2[,5], lty=1)
lines(dataset1[,6]~dataset2[,5], lty=2)
    ##### PROBLEM IS HERE WITH LTY=2 ####
```

The graph gets returned as 2 solid curves (rather than 1 solid and 1 dashed) and I can't figure out where the problem lies. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Ok, I will add a reproducible example.

Comment: It is off-topic because it is about how to use R. Lacking a reproducible example is a further difficulty making many of us reluctant to vote to migrate this to SO. Please review advice about software-related questions in the Help Center.

Comment: Enter the command capabilities(), and post the result

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could provide your data.  Here is an example of a plot with lines of various types.

```
plot(1:10, type='b',lty=2)
lines(1:2, lty=1)
lines(2:4, lty=2)
lines(3:6, lty=3)
lines(4:7, lty=4)
```

[image]